# How to start a Jmeter thread from another thread?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have Thread A that performs user login, setting some settings and creating some records. While working on the records page, there is a background thread, Thread B, that is being called every 15s, performs some sort of sycnronisation, but only when I'm on the records page.

What I managed to do is created a second thread that will fire these requests each 15s. Using a BeanShell PreProcessor I share the cookies between the two threads, so that the Http cookie manager in the second thread uses the same variables/values as the first one. My requests are working fine.

What I can't figure out is how to trigger Thread B when the Thread A has reached the step that involves records. One option is to delay Thread B for a certain amount of time, but this isn't very reliable as I can't know before hand how long it takes Thread A to finish creating the users.

Is there a way to trigger a thread from another thread?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) - it allows synchronizing actions between different threads (even if they are in different thread groups) basing on a simple [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue.

The logic would be:

- When you did some action by Thread A put something into the queue using `fifoPut` function
- Thread B will be scanning the queue and if anything comes up it will get the value and start execution of its own actions.

Check out [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan for reference implementation.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so kindly avoid Beanshell going forward.

Comment: The issue I'm encountering is that in `Thread B` I have a `Loop controller` which seems to be firing only once, I'm guessing it's because one I call `fifoPop` the queue is empty. Any idea where I should put the `jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor` in order to have "wait" for the signal in `Thread A`. Currently I am setting a flag there when I am done getting things ready, but I can't see to get `Thread B` configured correctly.